# How to handle multiple users for a device driver

Tags: drivers

I am learning to write device drivers. I came across a scenario where there are multiple programs which want to write to the same driver. Instead of showing them a busy error, I would like to place them in a queue and when one program has finished writing to it, the next in the queue gets to write and so on (i.e., handle multiple users).

So can `wait_event_interruptible()` and `wake_up_interruptible()` be used? Because most of the examples I have seen use to it block *read*.